# How to login programatically in Cypress E2E test using Next Auth JWT

Tags: next.js, jwt, cypress, next-auth, end-to-end

I want to login programmatically using Cypress. Login Through UI Works but I can't figure it out how to login programmatically.

```
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

// Login Form.
const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      await signIn("credentials", {
        email: email,
        password: password,
        redirect: false,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error", error);
    }
  };
```

Command to login programatically I followed next-auth **REST API** [docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api) Command I receive 200 success message but it won't login.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("loginPR", (email, password) => {
  cy.request("GET", "/api/auth/csrf").then((csrfResponse: any) => {
    const csrfToken = csrfResponse.body.csrfToken;
    cy.request("POST", "/api/auth/signin/credentials", {
      email,
      password,
      csrfToken,
    }).then((loginResponse) => {
      expect(loginResponse.status).to.equal(200);
    });
  });

  return cy.wrap(null);
});
```

[image: Error message]

**Here's the github** [repository](https://github.com/ArnasDickus/cypress-next-auth-programatic-login)

1. Most important files are **commands.ts** and **login.cy.ts**
2. Currently test is logging through UI. To test programatically update login.cy.ts

```
    // Working Example:
    // cy.loginUI("test@test.com", "kflsdfklsdfk");
    // cy.get('[data-testid="loggedInUser"]');

    // DOES NOT WORK
    cy.visit("/");
    cy.loginPR("test@test.com", "kflsdfklsdfk");
    cy.reload();
    cy.get('[data-testid="loggedInUser"]');
```

3. To run Cypress `npm run cypress:open`
4. Any email or password will login user.